# Piecewise linear optimisation using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to solve the following optimisation problem, whose objective function is independent of x:

minimise t

subject to a_i*x+b_i<=t

over x for all i from 1 to n=100

This problem arised from if I rewrite a piecewise linear optimisation problem to a linear optimisation problem.

**Question:**
How can I implement this in the matlab using `linprog`. In `linprog` I am asked to insert the objective function f as a matrix multiplying with x. Is it possible to have a objective function independent of x? If not, how am I going to implement this?

P.S: I don't know why Mathjax is not working here, I have been looking for how to ask questions with Math formula, but I was not successful. Therefore any correction is welcomed.

**Edit:**[Here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) is the official document from Matlab for `linprog`. In it it is stated that the minimalising function has the shape of f^Tx. My problem is just that my minimalising function doesn't take such shape and is in the absence of x. How can I implement this in the Matlab?

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you for your advice. I am struggling indeed with code implementation as in MATLAB the linprog function requires f^Tx as objective. I want to know if I can give only f to the objective without x. (With objective I mean the function that I am Minimalising and is not the constraint function.)

Comment: @Wolfie the x in the constraint function.

Comment: @Wolfie I think you misunderstood me. My minimalising function is just t. "x" just occurs in the constraints. This is equivalent to minimalising f(x)=max(a_i*x+b_i) over all i,(where now the x occurs in the objective function) Why I am rewriting this to the problem in the post is because the max function is only piecewise linear and the rewritten problem is linear. Thus I can use the linprog. You can see my problem as kind of I am minimalising the feasible area of t. If I find the minimal feasible area of t the optimum value of t is just f(x)=max(a_i*x+b_i) over all i.

Comment: @Wolfie I strongly assume that Matlab is using simplex-algorithm, and this methods will assume the objective fucntion to be linear and not only piecewise linear. The problem is, in simplex algorithm you will conduct operations like $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ which doesn't hold in a piecewise linear function.

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you for your patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reformulate your problem into standard LP, i.e. find the nominal `f`, `A` and `b` as required by MATLAB's function `linprog`.

Here is the reformulation. From your question it seems `x` and `t` are two scalars.

Assume the given `a_i`'s and `b_i`'s are stored in column vectors `a` and `b` respectively, then your original problem:

min `t`, s.t. `a * x + b <= t * ones(n,1)`

is equivalent to:

min `[0; 1]' * [x; t]`, s.t. `[a, ones(n,1)] * [x; t] <= -b`.

Thus, just use `linprog([0; 1], [a, ones(n,1)], -b)`, and the solution is `[x; t]`.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.